# How to modify KendoUI DropDownList items

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

We used the Kendo UI DropDownList the first time without binding with knockout.
Via jquery a usual html input is transformed into a KendoUI DropDownList.
But how can i remove/edit/add items to the options?

If i modify the html inputs options via jquery it has no influence on the kendoui dropdown - even with a refresh call afterwards.

Any ideas how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yo mate

You should use the [dataSource](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html) of the combobox.
e.g.

```
var ds = $('#YourCombo').data().kendoComboBox.dataSource;
```

then you can modify the items like this

```
//someIndex is the index of the item in the dataSource
ds.data()[someIndex].set("text","Cool! its changed");
```

to add item or remove use the **add** and **remove** methods of the dataSource

```
ds.add({text:"Test again!",value:"5"});
```

Comment: OP was actually asking about a kendoDropDownList but I've found that this method works just as well for DropDownLists as it does for ComboBoxes

Comment: In this case, what would I define as my datasource? do I need a datasource?