# Disabling KendoUI drop down list options

Tags: html, kendo-ui

How to disable an option of a kendoiu drop down list?
I couldn't find how to accomplish this in their documentation...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following approach ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/eQfh4/1/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eQfh4/2/) there are some demos): use a [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-template) for your items, which conditionally adds a class to the items to be disabled. The info about which items should be disabled comes from the underlying data objects.

HTML:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    #
    if (data.disabled != null) {# 
    <span class="tbd" > ${data.text} - is disabled </span> 
    # } else { #
    <span>${data.text}</span > #
    }#
</script>
<input id="color" value="1" />
```

jQuery and Kendo UI (note here the `disabled` extra property for the *Orange* item and the usage of the [dataBound event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#events-dataBound)):

```
var data = [{
    text: "Black",
    value: "1"
}, {
    text: "Orange",
    value: "2",
    disabled: "disabled"
}, {
    text: "Grey",
    value: "3"
}];

$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    dataBound: function (e) {
        $(".tbd").parent().click(false);
    }
});
```

CSS for graying out:

```
.tbd{
   color:#777777
}
```

Comment: This works but I am trying to find a dynamic approach and it doesn't seem possible so far

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This solution does not prevent keyboard navigation. See my answer below for an alternative.

Answer (score 7):

While the accepted answer will prevent a click on the item, it still allows keyboard navigation (and feels pretty hackish).

Using the DataItems to identify which item should be disabled is indeed the way to go, but instead of removing the click handler, it is simpler to implement a `Select` handler that will stops the chain. This method is [supported and documented](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-select) by Kendo :

> Fired when an item from the popup is selected by the user either with
>   mouse/tap or with keyboard navigation.
>
> ...
>
> e.preventDefault Function
>
> If invoked prevents the select action. The widget will retain the
>   previous selected item.

All that remains is to detect if we want to cancel the selection or not, which is trivial if your data item keeps a property that identifies whether it is available or not :

```
function Select(e) {
    if (e.sender.dataItem(e.item).disabled) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Using a template to inject a specific class is not needed, but I would still recommend it if only to enable a proper styling.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336989/how-to-modify-kendoui-dropdownlist-items), you could access the relevant item and change attributes like so:

```
var ds = $('#YourCombo').data().kendoComboBox.dataSource;

//someIndex is the index of the item in the dataSource
ds.data()[someIndex].set("enabled","False");
```

Comment: I ca see how this works for the text, but not sure that it will work out for disabling the option.. should there be some additional binding on the dropdown list?

Answer (score 4):

Kendo currently doesn't support such functionality but this is easiest hack I found to disable an option in Kendo Dropdown.

```
$("#" + id + "_listbox .k-item")[index].disabled = true;
```

where id -> ID of your dropdown
      
      index -> position of the element in the dropdown you want to disable.

Hope it helps. Enjoy :)

Comment: how would you gray-out that item then?

Comment: this is crazzy... i loved it .. what a quick and perfect solution

Comment: @Shardul : You can try this, it works 
$("#ID.k-item")[0].style.cssText = "color: lightgrey"

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
 var dropDown = $("#yourDropdown").data("kendoDropDownList");
 dropDown.enable(false);
```

---

```
Try other way for specific index

var dropDown = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
$("#color" + "_listbox .k-item")[index].disabled = true;
$("#color" + "_listbox .k-item").eq(index).addClass("tbd");

Fiddler for reference :-  http://jsfiddle.net/xLs4n9dm/2/
```

Comment: This will just  disable the dropdown. The OP wanted to disable just an item.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to disable the entire control and you are using the MVC fluent API, then you can use the .HtmlAttributes() method:

```
@Html.Kendo()
.DropDownList()
.HtmlAttributes(new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score -4):

Try like this

```
    $('#YourDropDown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: This disables the drop-down list, not an option.